# Trying to understand the implications of DPI on MapView overlays on Android

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, dpi

I am porting a Google Maps Javascript v3 API web application over to a native Android application.  In my web application, I use custom map tiles.  Because the Android implementation of Google Maps does not support custom tiles, I have stitched my images back together (one image for each zoom level) and based on the current zoom level just overlay the entire relevant image, rather than tiling (my images are smallish, so I can do this).

The problem I am having is that the overlay is only positioned correctly at one DPI.  For example, if I have all images in the `/hdpi` directory, the overlay is positioned correctly.  If I move all images into the `/ldpi` directory, the overlay is too large and so does not sit in the right place on top of the existing MapView Google maps imagery.

I would like to know how to ensure that regardless of the devices DPI, my overlays will always be sized correctly to match the underlying MapView imagery.  The naive approach I have considered is just scaling the image by the relevant factors for the `/ldpi` and `/mdpi` directories, but if I am not mistaken, these are "rough" and in practice a device might be using a DPI anywhere between them.  Can anyone advise of an appropriate solution?